# Nginx location index being overwritten by try_files

Tags: nginx

I've recently set up [Gollum](http://www.github.com/github/gollum) with Nginx running the backend stuff.

The wiki repository is stored in `/path/to/root/todos` (it's a to-do wiki). Because of the way Gollum works, however, if it can't find a page on the wiki, it automatically tries to create one (which is great), but rewrites the url as follows:

`http://www.domain.com/todos/foobar` (doesn't exist yet and will be created) gets rewritten to `http://www.domain.com/create/foobar`. Now, unless I set up a separate entry for each possible  uri that Gollum uses in its own directives, we get a 404 error here.

To circumvent this, I added the following to my nginx config:

```

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri /$uri /todos/$uri;
}
```

```

This works, but it will not accept the index. If I go directly to `domain.com/index.php`, I can view the index page as intended. However, going directly to the site (`domain.com`) instead redirects to the index for the wiki. (`domain.com/create/home`). I don't understand this behaviour, as it is only supposed to route to to-dos (which is a `proxy_pass` directive to the Gollum port) if the original $uri can't be found, and `index.php` exists.

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like such a simple issue, but this doesn't make any sense to me.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this page when having the same issue, ≈2 years later.

My solution didn't involve any nginx hacking, but using the option flags in gollum. `--base-path`, should take care of this issue. Try instantiating gollum with:

`$ gollum /path/to/root/todos/ --base-path todos`

Answer (score 0):

Make a `location /todos/` block to contain the `try_files` directive since you are doing the redirecting if a non-existent URI is found only in the todo directory. And it's generally recommended to put the `index` directive in the server block if it's not different for different location blocks. (This is not relevant to this issue, though)

```
server {
    .............
    .............
    index index.php;

    location /todos/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /create/$uri;
    }

    ............
    ............
}
```

In your configuration, the second parameter for the try_files `/$uri` makes no sense unless you are trying to redirect `http://www.domain.com/todos/foobar` to `http://www.domain.com/foobar`. A succeeding front slash denotes a directory whereas a preceeding slash just denotes a root level file/directory.

Comment: `location /todos/` is where I have the proxy pass to the Gollum port. Gollum does not know about `/todos/`, and does not write URLs with `/todos/` in it. That is why I mentioned above that Gollum tries to reach the URL at `domain.com/create/foobar`, instead of `/todos/create/foobar`. The problem is that for some reason `index index.php` is being ignored, and try_files isn't attempting to find index.php first.